# Need to allow image to extend beyond window

Tags: html, image, width

How can I allow an image to extend past the edge of the browser window?

On small displays, the image forces the browser to resize the page which leaves the text too small. I can let the image become too small but I'd prefer to let the image extend past the right side of the screen.

To see the problem, view http://ladiesofliberty.org/chapters/ on a small screen and you'll see that the world map causes unpleasantness...

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the img **responsive** with

```
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* Center horizontally */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```